# use if else statement to judgement the action

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use the jquery draggable and want to use if else statement to judgement the different popup when I click the button,but it doesn't work,how can i do?

```
$(".btn-popup").on("click", () => {
  if ($(".year2").mouseout()) {
    $(".popup-1").show();
  } else if ($(".year58").mouseout()) {
    $(".popup-2").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: The `mouseout()` function is for creating a handler for the `mouseout()` event, or triggering the event. It doesn't return a true/false value.

Comment: What are you trying to test in those if conditions?